# Jenkins pipeline plugin and PTC Integrity SCM samples

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mks-integrity

We are using Jenkins with PTC Integrity as SCM.

I am trying to utilize the Pipeline plugin for some advance configurations. 
However, I am not able to find any samples or documentation.

From the [list](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md), it's clear that it's compatible,

I found this [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin/blob/master/README.md#generic-scm-step), where a custom scm check out can be done

When used below syntax for IntegritySCM,

checkout scm: [$class: 'IntegritySCM', configPath: 'xyz'] (and other info),

I am getting below error,

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.instantiate(DescribableHelper.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.coerce(DescribableHelper.java:576)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.buildArguments(DescribableHelper.java:524)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.instantiate(DescribableHelper.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:103)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:112)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1144)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1038)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:2)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14996.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14959.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot call getRootUrlFromRequest from outside a request handling thread
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getRootUrlFromRequest(Jenkins.java:1994)
    at hudson.scm.IntegritySCM.<init>(IntegritySCM.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.instantiate(DescribableHelper.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.coerce(DescribableHelper.java:576)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.buildArguments(DescribableHelper.java:524)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.structs.DescribableHelper.instantiate(DescribableHelper.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:103)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:112)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1144)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1038)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15)
    ... 30 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I am able to checkout with PTC Integrity (the constructor changes with the plugin version - Min version supported 1.36)

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'IntegritySCM',configurationName: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), serverConfig: 'd07fa304-80f4-abcd-93aa-xyz', configPath: '#/ProjectNameABC#d=1251652#Coding', cleanCopy: true], poll: false
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin/blob/master/README.md#generic-scm-step) for more information, unfortunately, PTC plugin has less to no documentation.